# number of unique strings in dictionary

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to calculate the number of possible substrings with the maximum length n in the dictionary of size $r$. I would think that it should be the number of total subsets (of all sizes) in set of $3$: $2^3=8$ but in the dictionary $\{A,B,C\}$ for example, I've counted $19$:

```
AAA BBB CCC ABC CBA BCA BAC AA AB AC BB BA BC CC CA CB A B C
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Does the length of the alphabet dictates the maximum length of a word in the dictionary ? I mean why would "AAAA" not be a word ?

Comment: Isn't it true that $AAA$, $AA$, and $A$ all represent the subset $\{ A \}$?

Comment: You are right - my question is incomplete. What I am trying to ask is number of permutations of the string with max size of k when the number of letters is r

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your alphabet has $n$ letters. Then there will be $ n^k$ words of length $k$. Sum that from $1$ to $r$ if $r$ is the maximum length of a word.

In your question you missed many of the three letter words (for example, AAB). If you write them in alphabetical order you will see the pattern.

Your guess about $2^3$ is right when you are counting subsets, but in a dictionary the order in which the letters appear in a word matters.

Related: [Finding total possible permutations of n elements, in strings of n length (Math-Challenged person!)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694439/finding-total-possible-permutations-of-n-elements-in-strings-of-n-length-math/2694450#2694450)